# How would I use an sql query with .where to check for a match between a date column and a string?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, rails-activerecord

I have a hunch that this is sort of a hack already, but I was curious about this nonetheless:

Say I have this:

```
current_user.memories.where("content LIKE '%#{search}%' OR note LIKE '%#{search}%' OR date LIKE '%#{search}%'")
```

This is for a search field.

In my database, in the 'memories' table, I have **content:text and note:string**, so up through the first two compares, this trick works fine.

However, the date part doesn't work, obviously. I have a **date:date** column in the memories table too, but I don't know how to check for a match with the string.

I am fine with formatting the string to something like 2013-01-15, but I don't know how to do this comparison. Somehow change the 'date' part into that string too?

The idea behind this whole thing is to allow a search like 2013-01-15 (or some format) which would automatically check for dates too for 'memory' objects.

Advice appreciated.

(The db is postgres if that matters.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't be using string interpolation to build SQL, let ActiveRecord take care of that stuff. Secondly, if your `search` is in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8601) format (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD) then you could directly compare the date column with the string use `=` and PostgreSQL will figure it out. You want something more like this:

```
current_user.memories.where(%q{
       content like :pat
    or note    like :pat
    or date       = :date
}, :pat => "%#{search}%", :date => search)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your search term into a date by using to_date(text, text). You may also have to remove the time component from your date field if necessary

An explanation is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-formatting.html)